# Create a HTML Title Box via JS

Tags: javascript, html, title

Is there a way to display a title box without creating a html element with title="something" attribute and moving the mouse over it?

Something like: `document.tooltip = "Google";`

that would display http://puu.sh/67Fub.jpg without having to move the mouse over the Google image nor needing the image in the first place.

Comment: Not without creating html elements - if you are trying to replicate the effect without having to hover, you could always place a div in front of another using css positioning - is this what you are looking for?

Comment: You can use [jQuery Plugins](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) to do it or else you can use [HTML5 Data Attributes](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-tooltips-courtesy-of-html5-data-attributes/) to do it

Answer (score 1):

You could do something with CSS, using the :before or :after psuedo-elements ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kFqP7/)):

```
<div>Hello world</div>
```

```
div {
    position: relative;
}

div:hover:after {
    content: 'foo bar';
    position: absolute;
    background: cornsilk;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #222;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #222;
}
```

To take it a step further, you can do it dynamically like this (just an example):

```
var text = $('input').val();

$('div').attr('data-content',text);
```

```
div:hover:after {
    content: attr(data-content);
    /*plus all the other stuff*/
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but I want to be able to display the tooltip without needing any html element to be present.

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<div id="container">
  <div style="width:140px;">
   <h1 id="text">GOOGLE</h1>
  </div>   
</div>
```

js:

```
  var tile = $('<div />').appendTo('#container');
      tile.attr('id','tile');
      tile.text('google');
      tile.css({
           'background-color':'cornsilk',
            width:'50px',
            height:'20px',
            'position': 'absolute',
            'display': 'none',
            'box-shadow': '1px 1px 1px 1px #222',

             });

       $('#text').on('mouseover',function(e){
        tile.show();
        tile.css({
        'left': e.pageX + 'px',
        'top': e.pageY + 'px'
        });
    });

       $('#text').on('mouseout',function(e){
         tile.hide();
        });
```